# Reuse a set of XSLT conditions for different output (in this case amp-analytics configuration)

Tags: xslt, google-analytics, amp-html

This is a hellish combination of technologies, but I have no choice. I need to output an `amp-analytics` configuration object on an AMP HTML page that gets rendered with XSLT. The docs for configuration are [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md#variable-definitions) just in case.

Look at this part of the configuration. You need to output a key in "vars" attribute for each of the variables you need to send to analytics. But you also need to include their names in a request query string. There can be several requests.

```
{
  "requests": {
    "pageview": "https://example.com/analytics?url=${canonicalUrl}&amp;title=${title}&amp;acct=${account}&amp;clientId=${clientId(cid-scope)}",
  },
  "vars": {
    "account": "ABC123",
    "title": "Homepage"
  }
}
```

I have an XML list of the variables:

```
<vars>
    <account>111</account>
    <title>222</title>
    <foo>333</foo>
</vars>
```

In my XSLT I go like that:

```
<xsl:if test="/vars/account">
    "account": "<xsl:value-of select="/vars/account" />",
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/vars/title">
    "title": "<xsl:value-of select="/vars/title" />",
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/vars/foo">
    "foo": "<xsl:value-of select="/vars/foo" />",
</xsl:if>
```

Okay, that's ugly but fine. But now I have to explicitly include all these variables in every request in `requests` attribute like `&amp;title=${title}&amp;acct=${account}&amp;cd1=${foo}`. Here I get lost.

I don't want to duplicate all the logic for outputting a query string. The only thing I came up is to make a named template with a parameter and call it for each request:

```
<xsl:template name="vars">
    <xsl:param name="for_query" select="1"/>    
    <xsl:if test="/vars/account">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$for_query = 1">&amp;account=${account}</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>"account": "<xsl:value-of select="/vars/account" />",</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="/vars/title">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$for_query = 1">&amp;title=${title}</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>"title": "<xsl:value-of select="/vars/title" />",</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="/vars/foo">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$for_query = 1">&amp;foo=${foo}</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>"foo": "<xsl:value-of select="/vars/foo" />",</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Imagine this a few times longer and a tad more sophisticated and you'll be no wonder why it makes my eyes bleed. Then i call it where appropriate:

```
{
  "requests": {
    "pageview": "https://example.com/analytics?url=${canonicalUrl}<xsl:call-template name="vars" />",
    "event": "https://example.com/analytics?url=${canonicalUrl}<xsl:call-template name="vars" />"
  },
  "vars": {
    <xsl:call-template name="vars">
        <xsl:with-param name="for_query" select="0"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    "look_ma": "no_comma"
  }
}
```

Any less barbaric solutions you'd recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `extraUrlParams`? They should let you specify params without touching the `request` and `vars` block.

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/amp-analytics.md#extra-url-params

Comment: Looks promising, going to try that. I was so pissed off I never went through the whole docs to discover this approach. Seems it can be used to print my vars only once with a simple template. Thank you!

Comment: We are always open to feedback. Feel free to open an issue on github if something is not working for you...